# Clear Quest Connect Options

Tags: oracle11g, clearquest

We have created a schema in orcale 11 database and when trying to map that to Clear Quest using maintanance tool, we are trying to create a new connection. While creating a new connection, it is failing to create the connection and the error message was:

CRMDB0049E This database was made with "long" datatypes. which are no longer supported. you must convert this database to use "clob" datatypes.

Can some one suggest how can we fix this error and establish a new connection.

I have provided all other details like server, database type, sid, user id and password.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`long2clob` tool documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.install_upgrade.doc/topics/c_long2clob_tool.htm) for detailed information.

I am currently helping a customer do just this, We had to move from Oracle 8 to 10 then run `long2clob` tool, then upgrade the Database to a supported feature level (7), then convert the database from 10 to 11!